# All of the solution of $y^{(33)}(x)-y^{(30)}(x)=e^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Find all of the solution of the following differential equation s.t. $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{y(x)}{x^2}=0$
$$y^{(33)}(x)-y^{(30)}(x)=e^{-x}$$

I have immediately dismissed the idea of using the variation of parameters method, since I need 33 linearly independent solutions of the homogeneous; however, putting it into a system is leading nowhere. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this:
$$y^{(33)}(x)-y^{(30)}(x)=e^{-x}$$
$$y^{(31)}(x)-y^{(28)}(x)=e^{-x}+C_1x+C_2$$

---

$$y^{(5)}(x)-y^{(2)}(x)=e^{-x}+\sum_{i=0}^{27}C_{i}x^{i}$$
$$y^{(3)}(x)-y(x)=e^{-x}+\sum_{i=0}^{29}C_{i}x^{i}$$
The differential equation is of order 33 so you need 33 constants.

---

Since the differential equation is linear you can solve this apart:
$$y^{(3)}(x)-y(x)=e^{-x}$$
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$\implies r^3-1=0 \implies (r-1)(r^2+r+1)=0$$
$$\implies r=1, r=-\dfrac 12 \pm i\dfrac {\sqrt 3}2$$
The solution of the homogeneous equation is:
$$y(x)=e^{-x/2} \left (A \cos (\dfrac {\sqrt 3 x}2)+B\sin(\dfrac {\sqrt 3 x}2) \right)+Ce^x$$
For the particular solution try:
$$y_p(x)=Fe^{-x}$$
$$-Fe^{-x}-Fe^{-x}=e^{-x} \implies F=-\frac 12$$
So the general solution of the DE is:
$$y(x)=e^{-x/2} \left (A \cos (\dfrac {\sqrt 3 x}2)+B\sin(\dfrac {\sqrt 3 x}2) \right)+Ce^x-\frac 12e^{-x}$$

---

In absence of initial conditions the solution is:
$$y(x)=e^{-x/2} \left (A \cos (\dfrac {\sqrt 3 x}2)+B\sin(\dfrac {\sqrt 3 x}2) \right)+Ce^x-\frac 12e^{-x}+\sum_{n=0}^{29}a_{n}x^{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Do you know any functions which, if you differentiate them $30$ times, give you zero? That should dispose of most of your linearly independent solutions for the homogeneous equation.

[I think the question is a good one for testing understanding, so once you have solutions, you will have to think carefully]

Comment: The simplest $x^{29}$ and I see your point, but the Wronskian will be huge. So, there is something that eludes me for the moment

Comment: @F.inc So think polynomials - you haven't identified what I would call the simplest - what is the dimension of the space of polynomials which satisfy the differential equation? If you eliminate the polynomials from consideration you can leave yourself with a simpler problem. Then you need to bring the polynomials back when you consider the solutions which satisfy the other condition. Split the solution into manageable pieces rather than trying to do it all at once.

Answer (score 1):

If we let $$U=\frac{d^{30}y}{dx^{30}}$$

Then we can begin first by solving the following equation:

$$\frac{d^3 U}{dx^3}-U=e^{-x}$$

$$\left(\frac{d^3 }{dx^3}-1\right)U=e^{-x}$$

$$U=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$$

It then must follow that

$$\frac{d^{30}y}{dx^{30}}=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$$

$$y=-\frac{(-1)^{30}}{2}e^{-x}+\sum_{m=0}^{29}C_{m}x^{m}$$

$\left[ C_{m} \right]$ is a set of 30 arbitrary constants.

Comment: The space of solutions should have dimension 33.

Comment: (Also, OP asks for the solutions that have a particular asymptotic behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** In terms of $u := y^{(30)}$, the differential equation becomes
$$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad u''' - u = e^{-x} . \qquad (\ast)$$

Trying the ansatz $u = A e^{-x}$ gives a particular solution $u_0$.

The homogeneous equation corresponding to $(\ast)$ is $$u''' - u = 0 ,$$
which can be solved using the usual method of finding the roots of the characteristic equation $$r^3 - 1 = 0 ,$$
giving three linearly independent solutions $v_1, v_2, v_3$.

Thus, the general solution to $(\ast)$ is
$$u_0 + A v_1 + B v_2 + C v_3 ,$$
and we need to solve
$$y^{(30)} = u_0 + A v_1 + B v_2 + C v_3 .$$
But notice that $u_0'' = u_0$ and (rearranging the homogeneous equation above) $v_i''' = v_i$, so we can write
$$y^{(30)} = u_0^{(30)} +  A v_1^{(30)} + B v_2^{(30)} + C v_3^{(30)} = (u_0 + A v_1 + B v_2 + C v_3)^{(30)},$$
and integrating gives the general solution
$$y = u_0 + A v_1 + B v_2 + C v_3 + \sum_{j = 0}^{29} a_j x^j$$ of the differential equation in $y$. (This solution has 33 parameters, as expected.)
All that remains is to do is check which solutions satisfy the asymptotic condition $$\lim_{x \to \infty} y = 0 ,$$ but the forms of $u_0, v_1, v_2, v_3$ make this straightforward.